# for each line of a file, grep a specific string and make string substitution

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file containing more than 14000 records.
What I want to do is to process this file line by line and replace a String by anodher string returned by grep command.
For example:
Line :

```
/xxxxx/xxxxx/Class.java:67: Logger.w(TAG, "message");
```

My grep command to get **Class.java** string is (Class.java is juste an example):

```
grep -o '[a-zA-Z]*"*\.java"*'
```

I must, for each line, replace the **TAG** string by the **class.java** string return by grep command

Comment: You need `sed` instead of `grep`.

Comment: could you post example output for two different files? it's unclear whether you want the literal `class.java` or whether this is a string derived from the processed filename (and is it meant to be lower-cased?)

Comment: Class.java is just an example.
I have for example MainActivity.java LoginActivity.java etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` and do the following:

```
sed -r 's#(.*)/(.*)\.java(.*)(TAG)#\1\/\2\3\2#g'
```

Characters surrounded with parenthesis are *groups* that you can use in the second part to get their content.

In order to modify the file in-place, you should:

```
sed -ir 's#(.*)/(.*)\.java(.*)(TAG)#\1\/\2\3\2#g' your_file.txt
```

Comment: the first command works fine and in my terminal I see all TAG strings replaced by the right className but in the output file TAG strings remains the same.
the second command (whitch I need) return an error:
sed: -e expression n°1, caractère 39: référence \3 invalide dans le côté droit de la commande `s'
\3 reference is not valide in the right side of 's' command and I can't figure it out

Comment: I want to thank you for your reply. Finally I worked with the first command and stored the results seenin stdout to a file :)

Comment: @diego-bf I'm glad it helped you. I cannot understand the error you're getting, it's not English.

Comment: error message:
expression n°1, character 39: invalid reference \3 in the right side of the `s' \ 3 command

Answer (score 1):

This is where sed comes in:

```
sed -i 's/TAG/class.java/g' Class.java
```

do it for all java files in current directory (assuming bash here):

```
sed -i 's/TAG/class.java/g' *.java
```

`-i` means in-place, so replacing takes place inside the file and is saved immediately. For the rest I suggest you google about sed.

Comment: It's almost correct, you just need to support `.*\.java` instead of `class.java`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun thx. done. I'm not sure that's what the OP needs though.

Comment: He needs to replace TAG with what appears before `.java`, your answer still not correct.

Comment: I don't want to modify my java files.
I run a grep command on all my java files to get all lines containing Logger lines and I stored them in a log.txt file.
Now I'm dealing only with that new file. I must process this file line by line and grep the ***.java** string (with extension) to make it replace the **TAG** string

Comment: then don't use the `-i` flag: sed will output to stdout

Comment: @diego-bf may I ask what you need this for?

Comment: I have an android project and it contains many log lines that I want to fech in a single file. grep command suits me because besides giving me the lines I want, it gives the full path of the file, the file name and the line number

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
grep -rl 'old_string' ./ | xargs sed -i 's/old_string/Relacement_String/g'
```